# 48K csv files, 1000 lines each. How to redesign the data storage?

Tags: sql, r, hdf5, bigdata

This question was put on hold because it was too general.  I'm revising to be more specific.

One of the people that I help decided to scale up a simulation exercise to massive proportions.  The usual sort of thing we do will have 100 conditions with 1000 runs with each one, and the result can "easily" fit into a single file or data frame. We do that kind of thing with SAS, R, or Mplus. This one is in R. 
I should have seen trouble coming when I heard that the project was failing for lack of memory. We see that sometimes with Bayesian models, where holding all of the results from chains in memory becomes too demanding.  The fix in those cases has been to save batches of iterations in separate files. Without paying attention to details, I suggested they write smaller files on disk as the simulation proceeds.

Later, I realized the magnitude of my error. They had generated 48,000 output CSV files, in each of which there are 1000 lines and about 80 columns of real numbers.  These are written out in CSV files because the researchers are comfortable with data they can see.  Again, I was not paying attention when they asked me how to analyze that. I was thinking small data, and told them to stack up the csv files using a shell script. The result is a 40+GB csv file. R can't hope to open that on the computers we have around here.

I believe/hope that the analysis will never need to use all 40GB of data in one regression model :)  I expect it is more likely they will want to summarize smaller segments. The usual exercise in this ilk has 3 - 5 columns of simulation parameters and then 10 columns of results from analysis.  In this project, the result is much more massive because they have 10 columns of parameters and all of the mix and match combinations made the project expand.

I believe that the best plan is to store the data in a "database" like structure. I want you to advise me about which approach to take.

1. Mysql? Not open anymore, I'm not too enthusiastic.
2. PostgreSQL?  Seems more and more popular, have not administered a server before.
3. SQlite3?  Some admins here supply us with data for analysis in that format, but never have we received anything larger than 1.5GB.
4. HDF5 (Maybe netCDF?) It used to be (say 2005) these specialized science style container database-like formats would work well. However, I have not heard mention of them since I started helping the social science students. Back when R started, we were using HDF5 and one of my friends wrote the original R code to interact with HDF5.

My top priority is rapid data retrieval.  I think if one of the technicians can learn to retrieve a rectangular chunk, we can show researchers how to do the same.

Comment: Although no doubt an interesting problem (and one where I would lean towards a database), the question is either too broad or opinion-based for Stack Overflow.

Comment: 20GB csv file is not that big, it'll take a while but you can probably import the simulation data in a SQL database and then use [dplyr's database](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html) capabilities to select the data that you need for the analysis.

Comment: It indeed is a question of taste. My approach would be to use an SQL backend. And for the sake of not teaching SQL to the students, make some custom R functions for the data loading/saving.

Comment: Step 1 - Identify the purpose of the exercise.